# What happened to Sauron immediately after losing the One Ring?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium, the-one-ring, sauron

I watched and read LotR and Hobbit and there is no mention of the events after the Last Alliance overthrew Sauron.

I imagine that after Isildur cut off the Ring Sauron could be captured and for example taken to the Undying Lands to prevent him from corrupting Middle-Earth ever again.

So what happened after cutting the One Ring?